# Android(Activity not working need help beginner)

Tags: java, android, xml

My app stops working when I include lines below:

```
Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
ToggleButton passTog= (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonPass);
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
TextView display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewResults);
```

but when its gone it works

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subject);

    Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    ToggleButton passTog= (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonPass);
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
    TextView display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewResults);
}
```

can anyone one see a problem in the above

Comment: could you post your full code and logcat error ??

Answer (score 3):

```
EditText display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewResults);
```

or

```
TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResults);
```

You need to either change the display to EditText, or cast it as TextView